# CSS Grid Columns Too Close Together

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid below with  css.
In second row, The Document Date is Too close to Document Number. I tried changing 1fr to 3fr, didn't work.

```css
.titles-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles-grid">
  <div class="first-column">Document Number</div>
  <div class="second-column">Created</div>
  <div class="first-column">{{documentApnIncorporatorData.documentNumber}}</div>
  <div class="second-column">{{documentApnIncorporatorData.documentDate}}</div>
</div>
```

I was going to add the following with margin-left. Just curious if there isa more professional with css grid, to separate the column spacing.

```
.second-column {
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: read about gap ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

- [`grid-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)
- [`grid-row-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap)
- [`grid-column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap)

to add spacing to the grid

For example

```css
.titles-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles-grid">
  <div class="first-column">Document Number</div>
  <div class="second-column">Created</div>
  <div class="first-column">{{documentApnIncorporatorData.documentNumber}}</div>
  <div class="second-column">{{documentApnIncorporatorData.documentDate}}</div>
</div>
```

Note that `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap` are being phased out for `row-gap` and `column-gap` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `column-gap: 2rem;` in `rem` or `px` as you want.

```css
.titles-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 2rem; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="titles-grid">
  <div class="first-column">Document Number</div>
  <div class="second-column">Created</div>
  <div class="first-column">{{documentApnIncorporatorData.documentNumber}}</div>
  <div class="second-column">{{documentApnIncorporatorData.documentDate}}</div>
</div>
```